# Removing grouping from PivotTable columns

Tags: excel

My apologies if this question is posted elsewhere, but I believe part of my problem is that I'm not familiar with the terminology. Searching becomes rather difficult when you don't know the keywords to use...

I've inherited a PivotTable that pulls data from an SQL database. Three of the columns in this table are "grouped." By this I mean that all duplicate items in these columns are always next to each other. I want to removing these groupings so that sorting the table is easier. Does anybody know how to do this?

EDIT:My work computer has both snipping tool and paint disabled...So here is a picture of something similar. In my table, all of the data is pulled from the database. The left two columns (in this example) have repeated data, so it groups them like so. These sections are collapsible and expandable.

[image]
<sub>(source: [datapigtechnologies.com](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/040212_1021_FilltheEmpt1.png))</sub>

Comment: Can you post a picture of the grouping?  You can blur the details if they're sensitive, but "grouped" has several meanings in Pivot Tables and I don't want to burn 10 comments figuring out which usage you have.

Comment: Added further explanation to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option on the Pivot Table menu `Design->Report Layout->Repeat All Item Labels`.  This will repeat all the labels when combined with a `Tabular` or `Outline` style layout.  You will also do better (more than likely) to remove the subtotals as well.

**Menu and before**

[image: before]

**After**

[image: after]

Comment: This is close, but i want to remove the grouping all-together. Those sections interfere with sorting

Comment: You will have to convert to table to or somehow break out of the PivotTable... it's not made to sort like a normal table.  Try right clicking and `Show Details` to get the underlying data in a Table that can be sorted like you want.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well.  Remove ALL filtering so you ONLY have those two columns at once.  Once all filtering is removed it will allow you to ungroup them and the extra column will go away.